# looking for x-platform python console library

Tags: python, console, curses

I'm a Python newbie.

I need something like Curses library for Python 2.6 or 3.1 to run on Windows and Linux without any code changes.

I need functions for colorizing text and background, for clearing screen, for reading key code without showing letter on screen and for moving text cursor to specidied position.

It must be completely free library.

When I try "import curses" on Windows, compiler says me "ImportError: No module named _curses" both on Python 2.6 and 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone out there is still looking for a curses solution on Windows, here is a site which has **[PDCurses-based builds of the standard Python curses module for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses)**, and covers a pretty wide range: **32-bit and 64-bit, for Python versions 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2**.

[PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) is "a public domain curses library for DOS, OS/2, Win32, X11 and SDL".

Answer (score 1):

There is also urwid.
http://excess.org/urwid/

Answer (score 0):

See [curses-like library for cross-platform console app in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244897/curses-like-library-for-cross-platform-console-app-in-python) which links to wcurses, a windows library that provides some amount of compatibility with ncurses.

Comment: but it's license says it's not free!

Also I tried it on Python 2.6 and got an error:

"from _WCurses import *
ImportError: DLL load failed"

but _WCurses.pyd is in folder!