# So I would like to start making my own terminal based game, is this feasible?

Tags: python, terminal, cross-platform

Some basic requirements and desires:

- Windows/Mac/Linux
- Run as "full screen" within the terminal window, resizes as needed.
- Network multi player (loose requirement, although definitely would like to)
- Basic sounds
- Would like to write in Python since I'm learning that.
- Distributable as a single package, as in no run time dependencies that aren't built in or fairly commonplace.

Am I proposing something impossible? 
Is Python up to the task?
Will I have trouble with Windows terminal?

I'm not necessarily hellbent on using Python, however I've been learning it for other purposes, so I'd like to "keep it in the family" if at all possible.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [curses-like library for cross-platform console app in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244897/curses-like-library-for-cross-platform-console-app-in-python)

Comment: Refer to the "Python Roguelike" example code, `pyro`. It's an engine for roguelike games like, well, Rogue, or `nethack`, `angband`, etc. It should already have all the hard parts (termcap, curses) implemented for you. You just bring your own game mechanics. ;)

Answer (score 5):

While not a complete solution, I think [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) gives you most of the building blocks you need.

- It is a cross-platform terminal library, proven to work on Windows, OSX and Linux.
- It is designed to run full screen, handling terminal resizing.
- It is written in Python.
- It can be installed simply using pip.

You can get a flavour of the possible visual effects from the [gallery](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/wiki), but you might want to download the samples and try the sample called `interactive.py` to see how the Sprites work with keyboard input.

You'd still have to look elsewhere for the sound and networking.  I would hope some of the existing [game libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGameLibraries) could help you there.

Oh, and full disclosure here: I wrote the asciimatics package.

Answer (score 1):

In this day and age, it would actually be easier to create a [pygame](http://www.pygame.org) tile-based game and set all its tiles to ASCII symbols, than it would be to create a real in-terminal game.

I advise you to do just that.

Comment: But then how would I play it in screen?! :) But it sounds like I may have to concede the terminal aspect.

Comment: @DanH he is telling you to create your own "fake" terminal instead of using the ones that are build into the OS.

Comment: I get it, but I liked the idea of playing the game in Gnu Screen :)

Answer (score 0):

Getting terminal size in a cross-platform and reliable way is far from trivial (see termcap, curses and such).