# Add/remove characters in python?

Tags: python

I have two things I need this for, these should explain what I mean:

1. To have a 'shell popup' of sorts, like `man` does, that can be removed when done
2. To have a blinking ellipsis (...) for visual effect

Is there any standard Python way to do this? Could I 'unprint' the last line and reprint it?

Comment: Look at @sirfz 's answer in here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30203228/2966288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [curses](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/curses.html) module.

See also: [curses-like library for cross-platform console app in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244897/curses-like-library-for-cross-platform-console-app-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with it, but you may want to look at Python's interface to the `curses` library: http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html